# Opentok getting "VM Aborting" error

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webrtc, opentok

Tried to run [OpenTokRTC-Android](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC-Android) in android device but could not Join the room. App crashes after entering room when its trying to create instance of session. Here is the screenshot the scenario:

[image]

**Image 1: App crashes when trying to join room.**

[image]

**Image 2: Code for session instance declaration.**

User retrieved room response, settings room and enter into room successfully. Here is log information:

[image]

**Image 3: Log information on room status.**

[image]

**Image 4: Loaded the JNI file successfully.**

[image]

**Image 5: "VM Aborting" error from JNI file.**

VM aborting is happening from the side of Opentok **libopentok.so** file in which don't have access. So what should do in this situation?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy to simulator or a device? What is your device version?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android SDK, there was a new version released a few days ago. http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/